# KeyboardView inside WebView

Tags: android, webview, keyboard, custom-keyboard, android-custom-keyboard

Is it possible to use a KeyboardView for input symbols inside a WebView? I want to hide the standard keyboard and use the one I defined for my app. What's the correct way to do this? Should I intercept touch event or somehow change my HTML/JS code? Many thanks in advance.